farm hydrant back flow preventer/antisiphon
I have a farm hydrant near my life stock tank.  The tank is filled from a short section of hose. I had a back flow preventer/anti siphon on the hydrant to prevent tank water from getting into the hydrant. It froze during our last cold spell. The tank has a heater in it to prevent freezing. Can I put the back flow preventer on the end of the hose while it remains under water?

It depends on the local regulations (and type of back-flow preventer). -- Note: it depends on how much it freeze and material (sometime it doesn't matter, or sometime if you keep running some water it is enough. I assume you have not a very hard freeze (else also the hydrant would be placed to be out of freeze).
